# How to bypass character filtering in XSS?

Tags: xss, javascript

I am solving XSS challenges. I found difficulty in one that filters the character "o" both uppercase and lowercase. I can run  tag. I have to call function "prettyRobot" to complete the cahllenge. But character "o" is filtered, I try to run with

> "eval("prettyR"+"o"+"b"+"o"+"t()")"

But did not succeed. And fromCharCode cannot be used since character "o" is also inclued in fromCharCode function. 
How can I bypass this?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Have you tried encoding it? For example prettyRobot HTML encoded is: &#x70;&#x72;&#x65;&#x74;&#x74;&#x79;&#x52;&#x6f;&#x62;&#x6f;&#x74;

Comment: I don't know about the context you're in, but it may be possible to iterate over all the functions in a certain class, and call the function if it starts with 'pretty'

Comment: I have tried encoding it. I used &#x70;&#x72;&#x65;&#x74;&#x74;&#x79;&#x52;&#x6f;&#x62;&#x6f;&#x74;(). But it says syntax error. So, it tried it within eval() but it banned another "v" and "V" characters. I have no way to continue. Please help me.